# adduser, addgroup "group in use"

Tags: users, busybox

I'm trying to create a System-Wide PulseAudio daemon *(I am aware of the security problems associated with that)*. However, I'm getting an access-denied error when playing through the PulseAudio daemnon (as root). I think it may be because the root user is not in the pulse-access group.

I tried adding it:

```
adduser root pulse-access
```

Which, unfortunatly gives me back this error:

```
addgroup: group 'root' in use
```

I am running on a small BusyBox, which doesn't has the fancier useradd, etc. commands.

Why can't I / How should I add a user to a specific group, having only access to these two commands?

*Running PulseAudio as System-Wide Daemon*
https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/SystemWide/

Comment: Does your busybox have a `usermod` command?

Comment: no, not present..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BusyBox may be compiled with FEATURE_ADDUSER_TO_GROUP disabled (default behaviour of buildroot-2017.08). If that's the case addgroup or adduser cannot be added to a group. At least in theory, because when I enabled the feature I still got the same error.

**Easy solution**: just edit /etc/group directly, and add the user there yourself. For example:

```
pulse-access:x:1003:pulse,root
```

When doing it for a buildroot build, you may want to add this in the fakeroot scripts step:

```
# Add root user to pulse-access group
if [ -e ${TARGET_DIR}/etc/group ]; then
    sed -i '/^pulse-access:/s/\(.*\)/\1,root/;s/:,/:/' ${TARGET_DIR}/etc/group
fi
```